NoSuchElementException somewhere in DataStore
I have an Android application that stores simple values using Preferences DataStore. I do not have any instances of Proto Datastore.
The problem is, completely randomly my app starts crashing when launching, usually after cleaning user data too many times. I don't have any clue why this is happening since it seems to trigger even without messing with my DataStore repository.
This is the MainActivity (the ony Activity):
...

val Context.dataStore: DataStore<Preferences> by preferencesDataStore(name = "settings")

class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    companion object {
        var isForeground = false
    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        isForeground = true

        qrCodeConfiguration()
        notificationsConfiguration()

        setContent {
            val navController = rememberNavController()

            val mainviewModel: ComprinhasViewModel = viewModel()
            val settingsViewModel: SettingsViewModel = viewModel()
            val receiptsViewModel: ReceiptsViewModel = viewModel()

            ComprinhasTheme {
                NavHost(navController = navController, startDestination = "home") {
                    navigation(startDestination = "welcome/username", route = "welcome") {
                        composable("welcome/username") {
                            UsernameScreen { username, newList ->
                                navController.navigate(
                                    "welcome/setList/$username/$newList"
                                )
                            }
                        }

                        composable(
                            route = "welcome/setList/{username}/{newList}",
                            arguments = listOf(
                                navArgument("username") { type = NavType.StringType },
                                navArgument("newList") { type = NavType.BoolType }
                            ),
                            enterTransition = {
                                slideIntoContainer(AnimatedContentTransitionScope.SlideDirection.Start)
                            },
                            popExitTransition = {
                                slideOutOfContainer(AnimatedContentTransitionScope.SlideDirection.End)
                            }
                        ) {
                            val username = it.arguments?.getString("username") ?: ""
                            val newList = it.arguments?.getBoolean("newList") ?: false
                            val uiFlow = mainviewModel.uiState

                            SetListScreen(uiFlow = uiFlow, newList = newList) {listName, listPassword ->
                                if (newList) {
                                    if (
                                        mainviewModel.createList(username, listName, listPassword)
                                        ) {
                                        navController.popBackStack("home", inclusive = false)
                                    }
                                }
                                else {
                                    settingsViewModel.updateUserPrefs(username, listName, listPassword)
                                    navController.popBackStack("home", inclusive = false)
                                }

                            }
                        }
                    }
                    composable("home") {
                        HomeScreen(
                            viewModel = mainviewModel,
                            toWelcomeScreen = { navController.navigate("welcome") },
                            toSettingsScreen = { navController.navigate("settings") },
                            toReceiptsScreen = {
                                navController.navigate("receipts")
                                receiptsViewModel.getReceiptsList()
                            },
                            showDialog = { navController.navigate("addItem") }
                        )
                    }
                    composable("settings") {
                        SettingsScreen(
                            appPreferences = settingsViewModel.appPreferences,
                            updateUserPrefs = settingsViewModel::updateUserPrefs,
                            onNavigateBack = navController::popBackStack
                        )
                    }
                    composable("receipts") {
                        ReceiptsList(
                            receiptsFlow = receiptsViewModel.receiptsList,
                            onQrCodeScan = receiptsViewModel::scanQrCode,
                            uiFlow = receiptsViewModel.uiState,
                            onNavigateBack = { navController.popBackStack() }
                        )
                    }

                    dialog("addItem") {
                        InputDialog(
                            onDismiss = navController::popBackStack,
                            setValue = {
                                mainviewModel.addShoppingListItem(ShoppingItem(nomeItem = it, adicionadoPor = settingsViewModel.appPreferences.name))
                            })
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    override fun onStop() {
        super.onStop()
        isForeground = false
    }

    private fun qrCodeConfiguration() {
        val moduleInstallCLient = ModuleInstall.getClient(this)
        val optionalModuleApi = GmsBarcodeScanning.getClient(this)

        moduleInstallCLient
            .areModulesAvailable(optionalModuleApi)
            .addOnSuccessListener {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Módulos disponíveis", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

                if (!it.areModulesAvailable()) {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "QRCode não está presente", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

                    val moduleInstallRequest = ModuleInstallRequest.newBuilder()
                        .addApi(optionalModuleApi)
                        .build()

                    moduleInstallCLient.installModules(moduleInstallRequest)
                        .addOnSuccessListener {
                            Toast.makeText(this, "Módulo instalado", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                        }
                        .addOnFailureListener {
                            Toast.makeText(this, "Falha ao instalar módulo", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                                .show()
                        }
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "QRCode está presente", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                }
            }
            .addOnFailureListener {
                // TODO: tratar falha na obtencao do leitor de qr code
            }
    }

    private fun notificationsConfiguration() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.TIRAMISU) {
            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                    this, Manifest.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS
            ) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, arrayOf(Manifest.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS), 101)
            }
        }
        // TODO: separação para melhor UX

        val name = "Adição e remoção de itens"
        val importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT
        val channel = NotificationChannel("list_notifications", name, importance)

        val notificationManager: NotificationManager =
            application.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager
        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel)
    }
}

This is my HomeScreen composable:
...
@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)
@Composable
fun HomeScreen(
    viewModel: ComprinhasViewModel,
    toWelcomeScreen: () -> Unit,
    toSettingsScreen: () -> Unit,
    toReceiptsScreen: () -> Unit,
    showDialog: () -> Unit,
) {
    val cartList by viewModel.cartList.collectAsState(initial = emptyList())
    val shoppingList by viewModel.shoppingList.collectAsState(initial = emptyList())
    val homeState by viewModel.uiState.collectAsState(initial = UiState.LOADING)

    val scaffoldState = rememberBottomSheetScaffoldState()
    val scope = rememberCoroutineScope()

    LaunchedEffect(key1 = 1) {
        if (viewModel.appPreferences.welcomeScreen) toWelcomeScreen()
        else viewModel.getShoppingList()
    }

    BottomSheetScaffold(
        topBar = {
            Surface {
                TopBar(
                    showDialog = showDialog,
                    toReceiptsScreen = toReceiptsScreen,
                    toSettings = toSettingsScreen,
                    uiState = homeState
                )
            }
        },
        sheetPeekHeight = 115.dp,
        scaffoldState = scaffoldState,
        sheetContent = {
            BottomBar(
                cartList = cartList,
                onRemoveItem = {
                    viewModel.removeFromCart(it)
                },
                onClearCart = {
                    viewModel.clearCart()
                    scope.launch { scaffoldState.bottomSheetState.partialExpand() }
                },
            )
        }
    ) {innerPadding ->
        if (homeState == UiState.LOADING) {
            Column(
                modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
                verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center
            ) {
                CircularProgressIndicator(
                    modifier = Modifier.width(32.dp)
                )
            }
        }
        else {
            ShoppingList(
                shoppingList = shoppingList,
                modifier = Modifier.padding(innerPadding),
                onMoveToCart = { viewModel.moveToCart(it) },
                onDelete = { viewModel.deleteShoppingItem(it) },
            )
        }
    }
}


This is my DataStore repository file:
...
data class AppPreferences(
    val welcomeScreen: Boolean,
    val name: String,
    val listId: String,
    val listPassword: String,
    val lastChanged: Long,
)

class PreferencesRepository(
    private val preferencesDatastore: DataStore<Preferences>,
    context: Context
) {

    private object PreferencesKeys {
        val WELCOME_SCREEN = booleanPreferencesKey("welcome_screen")
        val USER_NAME = stringPreferencesKey("user_name")
        val LIST_ID = stringPreferencesKey("list_id")
        val LIST_PASSWORD = stringPreferencesKey("list_password")
        val LAST_CHANGED = longPreferencesKey("last_changed")
        val UI_STATE = intPreferencesKey("ui_state")
    }

    val preferencesFlow: Flow<AppPreferences> = preferencesDatastore.data.map { preferences ->
        val welcomeScreen = preferences[PreferencesKeys.WELCOME_SCREEN] ?: true
        val name = preferences[PreferencesKeys.USER_NAME] ?: ""
        val listId = preferences[PreferencesKeys.LIST_ID] ?: ""
        val listPassword = preferences[PreferencesKeys.LIST_PASSWORD] ?: ""
        val lastChanged = preferences[PreferencesKeys.LAST_CHANGED] ?: -1
        AppPreferences(welcomeScreen, name, listId, listPassword, lastChanged)
    }

    suspend fun updateUiState(state: UiState) {
        preferencesDatastore.edit{ it[PreferencesKeys.UI_STATE] = state.ordinal}
    }
    val uiState: Flow<UiState> = preferencesDatastore.data.map {
        val e = it[PreferencesKeys.UI_STATE] ?: UiState.LOADED
        enumValues<UiState>().first { it.ordinal == e }
    }

    suspend fun updateNameAndListId(name: String, listId: String) {
        preferencesDatastore.edit { preferences ->
            preferences[PreferencesKeys.USER_NAME] = name
            preferences[PreferencesKeys.LIST_ID] = listId
        }
    }

    suspend fun updateUserPrefs(name: String, listId: String, listPassword: String) {
        preferencesDatastore.edit {preferences ->
            preferences[PreferencesKeys.WELCOME_SCREEN] = false
            preferences[PreferencesKeys.USER_NAME] = name
            preferences[PreferencesKeys.LIST_ID] = listId
            preferences[PreferencesKeys.LIST_PASSWORD] = listPassword
        }
    }
}

And finally, my stacktrace:
java.util.NoSuchElementException: Array contains no element matching the predicate.
  at com.example.comprinhas.data.PreferencesRepository$special$$inlined$map$2$2.emit(Emitters.kt:227)
  at kotlinx.coroutines.flow.internal.SafeCollectorKt$emitFun$1.invoke(SafeCollector.kt:15)
  at kotlinx.coroutines.flow.internal.SafeCollectorKt$emitFun$1.invoke(SafeCollector.kt:15)
  at kotlinx.coroutines.flow.internal.SafeCollector.emit(SafeCollector.kt:87)
  at kotlinx.coroutines.flow.internal.SafeCollector.emit(SafeCollector.kt:66)
  at androidx.datastore.core.SingleProcessDataStore$data$1$invokeSuspend$$inlined$map$1$2.emit(Collect.kt:137)
  at kotlinx.coroutines.flow.FlowKt__LimitKt$dropWhile$1$1.emit(Limit.kt:40)
  at kotlinx.coroutines.flow.StateFlowImpl.collect(StateFlow.kt:396)
  at kotlinx.coroutines.flow.FlowKt__LimitKt$dropWhile$$inlined$unsafeFlow$1.collect(SafeCollector.common.kt:114)
  at androidx.datastore.core.SingleProcessDataStore$data$1$invokeSuspend$$inlined$map$1.collect(SafeCollector.common.kt:114)
  at kotlinx.coroutines.flow.FlowKt__CollectKt.emitAll(Collect.kt:109)
  at kotlinx.coroutines.flow.FlowKt.emitAll(Unknown Source:1)
  at androidx.datastore.core.SingleProcessDataStore$data$1.invokeSuspend(SingleProcessDataStore.kt:117)
  at androidx.datastore.core.SingleProcessDataStore$data$1.invoke(Unknown Source:8)
  at androidx.datastore.core.SingleProcessDataStore$data$1.invoke(Unknown Source:4)
  at kotlinx.coroutines.flow.SafeFlow.collectSafely(Builders.kt:61)
  at kotlinx.coroutines.flow.AbstractFlow.collect(Flow.kt:230)
  at com.example.comprinhas.data.PreferencesRepository$special$$inlined$map$2.collect(SafeCollector.common.kt:113)
  at androidx.compose.runtime.SnapshotStateKt__SnapshotFlowKt$collectAsState$1.invokeSuspend(SnapshotFlow.kt:64)
  at androidx.compose.runtime.SnapshotStateKt__SnapshotFlowKt$collectAsState$1.invoke(Unknown Source:8)
  at androidx.compose.runtime.SnapshotStateKt__SnapshotFlowKt$collectAsState$1.invoke(Unknown Source:4)
  at androidx.compose.runtime.SnapshotStateKt__ProduceStateKt$produceState$3.invokeSuspend(ProduceState.kt:150)
  at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
  at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(DispatchedTask.kt:106)
  at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidUiDispatcher.performTrampolineDispatch(AndroidUiDispatcher.android.kt:81)
  at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidUiDispatcher.access$performTrampolineDispatch(AndroidUiDispatcher.android.kt:41)
  at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidUiDispatcher$dispatchCallback$1.run(AndroidUiDispatcher.android.kt:57)
  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:942)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
  at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:211)
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:300)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8296)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:559)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:954)
Suppressed: kotlinx.coroutines.internal.DiagnosticCoroutineContextException: [androidx.compose.ui.platform.MotionDurationScaleImpl@55e174a, androidx.compose.runtime.BroadcastFrameClock@164a6bb, StandaloneCoroutine{Cancelling}@24a27d8, AndroidUiDispatcher@ac6f731]

I already tried:

rebuilding project
deleting the whole project and cloning it again from git
removed most of the repository calls from MainActivity and HomeScreen


It is crashing at the line enumValues<UiState>().first { it.ordinal == e }. How does that predicate work when you hit the ?: UiState.LOADED case? You're comparing an ordinal to the actual value itself, which doesn't seem like it would ever true. If you write val e = UiState.LOADED, does it always crash there?

@ianhanniballake that might be the case. I've changed it to val uiState = flowOf(UiState.LOADED) and the app didn't crash

Would you accept that as a solution for your problem or do you need further help with it?

@Leviathan yes I would. I'd just like to get,  if possible, an explanation as to why it was crashing at that line and only after cleaning app data. was it because of the UiState.LOADED at the elvis operator?

Then it's now up to @ianhanniballake to convert their comment into an answer so that you can accept it. :)

It is crashing at the line enumValues<UiState>().first { it.ordinal == e }.
What you're doing there is comparing the ordinal (i.e., just an Int with the value of e.
You're using the following code for e though:
val e = it[PreferencesKeys.UI_STATE] ?: UiState.LOADED

This means when it includes the key for UI_STATE, you get an Int representing the oridinal that you previously saved.
However, when the key hasn't yet been saved at all, e becomes UiState.LOADED - i.e., the actual enum itself and not the ordinal of an enum value.
If you want e to always be an ordinal, you could instead use
val e = it[PreferencesKeys.UI_STATE] ?: UiState.LOADED.ordinal

You may only see this rarely when clearing data since you're effectively only running into this as a race condition, since as soon as you write the UI_STATE key at least once, this error cannot appear (well, unless you remove an enum value in an app update - don't do that :D)
